# How to replicate a Craft installation as a starting point

Tags: install, license

I want to create a basic Craft installation that I can use as my starting point. I don't want to just start with the Craft download, because there is a lot of common setup I don't want to repeat every time.

My problem is making sure I properly pay Pixel & Tonic for a new license each time I need one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relevant link: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement

But the TLDR is that purchases are tied to your `craft/config/license.key` file and the purchase will follow that file wherever it goes.

So as long as your replication script ignores that file, you'll get a fresh one tied to Craft Personal Edition the first time that Craft sees it's has an internet connection and you can make a new purchase.

Additionally, and regardless of edition, Craft will tie the `license.key` file to a domain when it thinks it's being run on a "public" domain.  [Here is how we determine what is public.](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain)

Even if Craft gets that wrong (maybe you develop on public staging domaina.com, but the site will ultimately be on a public domainb.com) and Craft ties the `license.key` file to the staging domaina.com, the worst that will happen is that when you deploy the `license.key` file to domainb.com, you'll get a alert in the control panel saying something to the affect of:

"This license.key file is already in use on domaina.com.  Would you like to transfer it to domainb.com?"

None of the site's functionality will be affected.

Comment: so a .gitignore of craft/config/license.key is all I need. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Jake Chapman's [Craft CMS - Boilerplate](https://github.com/imjakechapman/CraftCMS-Boilerplate) on GitHub. You simply copy or clone your Craft boilerplate for each new project, and then add a newly downloaded `craft/app/` folder (wich is already on the latest Craft version) with a new `license.key` file to it.