# How to handle license when duplicating entire website

Tags: license

I have two seperate clients on different domains but I'm developing very similar websites for each. If I duplicate the entire site and upload to new domain what is the best way of handling the license key for the duplicated site.

I'm assuming if I transfer the license, using the control panel message, then the other website's license will break.

Any help would be appreciated.

(edit: I want to pay for the license on the duplicated system without losing any data.)

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be enough to delete the license.key file under

```
craft/config
```

and purchase a new license. The key file will be re-generated.

Some more info in this [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/how-to-replicate-a-craft-installation-as-a-starting-point?rq=1), and here is how Craft decides if it is running on a [public domain](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain)

Comment: This is spot on, just delete your duplicate license key. Make sure your `config` folder is writable, so Craft can put a new license key file there.